# Aggregate number of features by country in Overpass

Tags: overpass-api, aggregation, overpass-turbo

Does Overpass (or Overpass Turbo) provide a mechanism for query like “show me the number of nodes tagged `foo=bar` by country”?

Output being something like this:

```
Country    Count
Estonia    5
Latvia     8
Lithuania  6
Poland     42683
Czechia    2653
Germany    1458
```

Doesn’t have to be nicely formatted, CSV would be fully sufficient.

Is that possible in Overpass? If so, how?

Comment: Overpass by Example has a number of examples. Did you check them already? https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_API_by_Example#Wiki_table_generator_.28since_0.7.54.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, yes, it is possible:

```
// Define fields for csv output
[out:csv(name, total)][timeout:2500];

//All countries
area["admin_level"=2];

// Count in each area
foreach->.regio(
  // Collect all Nodes with highway=milestone in the current area
  ( node(area.regio)[amenity=pharmacy];
    way(area.regio)[amenity=pharmacy];
    rel(area.regio)[amenity=pharmacy];);

  // assemble the output
  make count name = regio.set(t["name:en"]),
             total = count(nodes) + count(ways) + count(relations);
  out;
);
```

Adapt to your needs by:

- Dropping `node`, `way` or `area` if you are not interested in that object type
- Altering the set of tags for the objects to count
- Adding more tags of the country as fields
- Adding per-type counts as fields

In practice, however, these queries get huge and can quickly time out, giving you only partial results. If you are only interested in a certain area, you can try constraining the list of countries to iterate over by e.g. specifying additional attributes.