# Select more than one area using Overpass API

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

There are different ways to define search areas using Overpass API.

For example:

**Geocode area**

```
[out:json][timeout:25];

{{geocodeArea:Bonn}};

node[tourism=hotel](area);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

**Area query returning unique result**

```
[out:json][timeout:25];

area["de:amtlicher_gemeindeschluessel"="05314000"];

node[tourism=hotel](area);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Find [more details here in the Overpass API documentation](https://dev.overpass-api.de/overpass-doc/en/full_data/area.html).

But what if I want to define a set of areas that I want to use in an iteration afterwards (e.g. a set of selected large cities)? Is there a way to create something like an "array of areas" to be used for the following tag queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter by multiple areas, the [union statement](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Union) can be used.

Here's an example that shows the number of hotels within the largest German cities based on OpenStreetMap data (with the *foreach* part [inspired by this GIS SE answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/363854/52808)):

```
[out:csv(city, hotels)];
(
  {{geocodeArea:Hamburg}};
  {{geocodeArea:Berlin}};
  {{geocodeArea:München}};
  {{geocodeArea:Köln}};
  {{geocodeArea:Frankfurt}};
  {{geocodeArea:Stuttgart}};
);
foreach->.c(
  nwr(area.c)[tourism=hotel];
  make count city = c.set(t["name"]),
             hotels = count(nodes) + count(ways) + count(relations);
  out;
);
```